# How to give delay in java progrramming?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to draw number of rectangles one after another using a specific time .
I use thread.sleep() method but it is directly stop working of thread and not resume.

Comment: Are you doing this in Swing??

Answer (score 2):

Use [Thread.sleep(long millis)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) instead, on the worker thread.

Comment: Can you give more context? How exactly are you drawing rectangles? Some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Specify number of milliseconds in sleep:

```
Thread.sleep(2000); // two seconds
```

Note that you need to handle `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Note this is the minimum it will sleep for

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the sleep in another thread. If you put the sleep in your GUI-thread, the GUI will freeze.

edit: My bad, will leave this here as a side note comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Timer` and `TimeTask` classes.

See this [example](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Comment: this is the real solution. `Thread.sleep(...)` simply stops the execution of a thread during the provided time. With Timer and TimerTask you can schedule executions of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [java executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29). These can run for a fixed time. Inside each executor unit you can then draw a rectangle. (on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)) [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) API document has a useful example at the top

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate each draw in a separate `thread`. Create the separate `thread` for every loop of the sleep.

This way, you would separate the thread for `looping`, and the thread for `drawing`. Thus, removes the *freezing*.

```
public class RunTest implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // codes for drawing
    }

}
```

And in your main:

```
   try {
      while (true) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new RunTest());
        t.start();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
```

This will create an **infinite** number of Threads for you drawing. Just modify this loop.

See here for [threads](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/).